# Spring WS show WSDL definition at specyfic address

Tags: web-services, spring, wsdl

I have problem with displaying my WSDL. I have found a way to dynamic read it from my `XSD` schema and now i am doing this as:

```
<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="test"                                                           
    portTypeName="testPort"                                                         
    locationUri="/"                                                       
    targetNamespace="http://testnamespace">                               
  <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/test.xsd"/>                                                  
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>
```

this way i got under address : `localhost:localport/applicationname/id.wsdl` WSDL which in my case is : `localhost:8080/MyApp/test.wsdl`. 

Thing i want to achive is to display this `WSDL` after executing another request: `localhost:8080/MyApp/test.aspx?WSDL` 
 How can i edit my code to do so? Can anyone redirect me somewhere if it is described ? I thought about creating a `wsdl` file instead of `xsd` but do anyone have an example how to show under specyfic address `wsdl` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From mine experience  I recommend You modify your `proxy_ajp` configuration file add:

```
ProxyPass /MyApp/test.aspx?WSDL ajp://localhost:8080/MyApp/test.wsdl
```

then restart your `httpd`. After this operation all request coming for `localhost:8080/MyApp/test.aspx?WSDL` will giving the `localhost:8080/MyApp/test.wsdl` result